# Home page showing using Tomcat7 Maven plug-in but not using standalone Tomcat

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, maven, tomcat

I have this Spring MVC application that I am working on and things look really good until I tried to deploy on a staging server - then I ran into this issue.

Facts:

1. When I use the Tomcat 7 Maven plug-in with the following configurations all works well and dandy using `http://localhost:8080`.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <configuration>
     <warSourceDirectory>${webappDirectory}</warSourceDirectory>
     <path>/</path>
     <port>${httpPort}</port>
     <httpsPort>${httpsPort}</httpsPort>
     <keystoreFile>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/some.keystore</keystoreFile>
     <keystorePass>broadleaf</keystorePass>
     <password>broadleaf</password>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But when I deploy this same code on a standalone Tomcat that serves on port 8080 with `ROOT.war` - and I try using `http://localhost:8080` - I get a 404 error. But when I point to `http://localhost:8080/somepage` I get what I need.

This is a Spring MVC application that does not declare the welcome page in the `web.xml`, instead it declares a servlet:

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myservelet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:/applicationContext-servlet-cms-contentClient.xml/WEB-INF/applicationContext-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myservelet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Is there something else I need to do to Tomcat standalone to get it to work? All other pages are served correctly except the home page. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a controller defining the RequestMapping of "/"?

Try using "http://localhost:8080/" with the slash at the end and see what you get.

Comment: My original code does not have one since I am using a CMS. I tried adding one that works but it did not show all the pre initialized data of the page as some of the sections were not properly initialized. What I do not understand is why it worked with the plugin but did not on standalone?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tomcat-maven-plugin, but my assumption would be that the plugin defines a homepage for the initial mapping of "/" if one is not explicitly defined.

Comment: It's probably defined by the <path>/</path> portion of the plugin declaration.

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentation of the tomcat-maven-plugin - It looks like I'm right. When utilizing the plugin, it uses the  variable in the plugin definition to define the initial context.

You could modify the path to `<path>/MotaNginya</path>` and that would be your new homepage.

When not using the plugin, you will have to define the homepage or "/" url yourself.

Please see the [tomcat-maven-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html) documentation for your convenience. Search for "`Using a different context path"` on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 7 will host a default application on ROOT context. If you want to deploy something there, you need to uninstall that first. Also note that your app should be named ROOT.war or similar.